# Outlook Custom Ribbon to an Organisation

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I have a custom for that i call for from the organizational forms library in a macro that has been distributed to everyone in an organization via a script.

What i would like to do now is set everyone in the organization to have a custom group or tab on their outlook ribbon with said macro.

Is there a method of setting an organizational ribbon or am i able to access the ribbon via vb script.

i need to distribute this to quite a few machines and would prefer not to walk n disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create ribbon controls only from a COM addin.

See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=36 to get started.